# How to replace page content on forced reload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page called `index.html` which has `<div id ="header">` and `<div id = "midSection"` in it. `Header` has navigation elements and when user clicks on them i load different `.php` documents into `midSection` using JQuery (AJAX calls). 
One of the   `.php` documents has registration form, and on submit click i successfully post data into DB. I did prevent standard actions, so when when data is submitted no default redirects are happening.
 
What i'm trying to do is when data is posted to redirect user to `index.html` (force refresh), but  `header` changed into another div (for example `headerOnLogin`). Is there anyway to do so?

---

```
          else {
     $.post($("#regForm").attr("action"),
    $("#regForm :input").serializeArray(),
    function(info){ 
           //php script returns this key if data is inserted into database successfully     
                if (info == 4521789524355214852) { 

                //RELOAD PAGE, REPLACE HEADER IN INDEX.HTML

            }
               else{

                $("#errorArea").empty();
                $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
                $("#errorArea").fadeOut('15000', function() { });
                $("#errorArea").fadeIn('15000', function() { });
                $("#errorArea").text(info);
                   setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#errorArea").empty();
                           }, 5000);

               }            

    });
  }

      $("#regForm").submit(function() { // prevents redirecting to another page after submitting    form
         return false;
   });
```

---

Comment: You're reloading the whole page, not just the `midSection` DIV, when this happens?

Comment: @Barmar, yes i want to reload whole page, or at least to redirect to the same page with another `header`. Changing only `midSection` would be trivial as i already implemented functions to do so =/

Comment: Why not just submit the form using default action and when done updating DB redirect to index.php/index.html with some flag/content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reload the page using something like:

```
window.location = "index.html?header=headerOnLogin";
```

Then have the JavaScript in `index.html` check `window.location.search` to see if it has `header=headerOnLogin`, and display the new header DIV that you want.

Or you could use `index.php`, and the PHP script could check `$_GET['header']`.